# Subprojects var type in dsl

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am transitioning my code to Kotlin DSL and as i have multimodule app i have some hack to transition gralde tasks like clean, build etc to other modules. So i have following method in gradle:

```
private static def getSubProjectTasks(subprojects, taskName) {
    def tasks = []
    subprojects.each { Project project ->
        if (project.subprojects.size() == 0) {
            def relativeModulePath = project.path.replace(":feature:", "")
            tasks.add("$relativeModulePath:$taskName")
        }
    }
    return tasks
}
```

Now trying to transition into kotlin dsl i started with this way

```
fun getSubProjectTasks(subproject: Unit, taskName: String) {
    for(project in subproject) {
        if(project.subprojects.size() == 0) {

        }
    }
}
```

I am not really sure in Kotlin DSL what type `subproject` is? Is this just a collection or Unit or how to transition this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Iterable<Project>`, `List<Project>` or `Array<Project>`?

I am judging based on your groovy lambda `each`.

You can also change your `for` for a `map` and have a single line doing everything:

```kotlin
fun getSubprojectTasks(subprojects: List<Subproject>, taskName: String) = subproject.mapNotNull { project ->
  if(project.subprojects.size == 0) {
    null
  } else {
    "${project.path.replace(":feature:", "")}$taskName"
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what i was looking for and with really nice Kotlin sugar syntax :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: One more question regarding this what if i want to modify this to something like this: https://pastebin.com/5GvTR9jX that i want to add tasks ?

Comment: Then create your local variable `tasks` and initialize it as a `mutableListOf<String>()` and you'll be able to `add`, and `addAll`. I can also reccommend you take a look at the `buildList` method which is an idiomatic way of building lists of things in Kotlin. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html

Comment: You can convert any list into a mutable list by calling `.toMutableList()` method:

```stuff.map { it * 2} .toMutableList()```